# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un valor seleccionado de una tabla y enviarlo por POST en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

estoy empezando a aprender acerca Spring Boot y me he encontrado con un problema que no he podido resolver.

Resulta que yo creo citas medicas, para ello muestro un formulario y dentro hay una tabla en donde aparece una lista de doctores, en cada uno tengo un checkbox, y quiero que al seleccionar uno y darle al botón de crear la cita medica, se guarde el doctor que se selecciono (Al menos su id). No se como almacenar ese dato para enviarlo.

Este es mi html donde muestro el formulario y los doctores:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="navbar-brand">Crear Paciente</span>
    </nav>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/createa}" th:object="${medicalAppointment}" method="post">
        <p>Valor cuota: <input type="text" th:field="*{feeValue}"/></p>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr th:each="user: ${doctorList}" >
                <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${user.speciality}"></td>
                <td th:text="${user.experience}"></td>
                <td>
         <!-- Este es el checkbox en cada doctor, al darle click guardaría su id en una variable llamada idDoctor -->
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>fecha de la cita medica <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{medicalAppointmentDate}"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Algo así se ve el html cargando los doctores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que puedo hacer para almacenar ese dato al seleccionar el checkbox, o si hay una mejor solución para esto que quiero hacer. Otra solución que se me ocurrió, pero no tan practica fue mandar todos los datos a otra pagina, en donde esta la lista de doctores, y en cada fila agrego un botón, si se escoge un medico entonces con el botón finalizo el formulario. Pero como dije quiero evitar hacer esto

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo he intentado, pero si no me equivoco (basandome en estas respuestas: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37745535/1305745) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424715/thymeleaf-checkbox-bind-list-of-object)), en tu vista deberias de armar el input de checkbox (con un id escondido) de la siguiente manera:

```
<tr th:each="user, track: ${doctorList}" >
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{doctores[__${track.index}__]}.id" th:value="${user.id}" />
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{doctores[__${track.index}__]}.check" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Y para recibirlo del lado de tu controlador:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createa")
public String crearCitaMedica(@RequestParam(value = "cers") Doctor[] doctores,
                              ...) {
    ...
}

public class Doctor {
    private Boolean check;
    private Long id;

    //Setters y Getters
}
```